# Need Line graphics for an Application

Tags: android, graphics, android-animation

I am designing a game where user and computer play in alternate turns(like chess).
I have 30 imageviews in my application. In this game user clicks on one imageview and then on another empty imageview to play/make his move (as in chess where user clicks on one pawn and then on the location where he wants to move the pawn).

In my app, when the computer makes his move, it's very difficult for the user to notice which pawn has moved and to where (because unlike chess a player's pawns are all identical here).

So I want to include a graphic (or whatever you call it) which draws a line from the source imageview to the destination imageview, whenever the computer plays.

So how do I go about doing this?

I have read all (translate, rotate, scale, alpha, framebyframe animations), but I felt nothing suits my need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you animate the pawn and make the speed configurable?

Comment: animating the pawn is ok..but how do i make the speed configurable?? do u mean by setting the duration in the alpha/translate...? those all make my application look really messy because they are all 2d animations...can you please tell me how do i draw lines as i asked(with the 3d effect) or how do i bring 3d effect to the translate animation?

Comment: Yes by setting the duration or by even allowing the user to switch it off. You never mentioned 3D in the question. A quick hack might be by scaling the image up during the translation thereby suggestion the pawn getting closer to the viewer provided you are using a top-down view.

Comment: hey erno what do you mean "by even allowing the user to switch it off" and "top-down view" ?...

Comment: Some users may find animations annoying so you might provide a way of turning them off. Top-down view is when you see the board from above straight down. In that perspective scaling the pawns bigger will make them appear to come towards you.

Comment: u should have known tht in these animations(translate,scale...) actually the content in the imageview(pawn in my case) moves around and comes back to the same imageview.....how do i make users feel tht the pawn is moving from one imageview to another(i tried translate but it doesn't look convincing)..if possible using 3d...i appreciate ur support till now...and hope u continue.plzz

Comment: Sorry, you keep on adding new information that should have been in the question. This makes it hard to give a correct answer. Could you post images of what you have/are trying to accomplish and add those to the question? (try to write proper English, no 'u', 'tht', 'ur' etc.)

Comment: You can post a url to the image

Comment: i cant post picture as i don't have enough reputation.i have 3 different drawables(a white ,an orange one & a yellow circle) that the 30 imagview's in my game can contain.i use a white drawable to indicate that the position is empty. imagine three imageviews in a row with the first two imageview's containing orange  and yellow circles. when the computer plays the orange circle should jump over the left one and occupy the empty(white circle).so now the  first imageview and the second imageview are empty( white circle) and the third imageview contains the orange drawable.

Comment: Have you tried animating the imageviews instead of the drawables? (Please add the descriptions to the question so others will find them too)

Comment: for that i change all the drawables that the the imageview's contain with new drawables accordingly using "Iv[i1][j1+1].setImageResource(R.drawable.sq);"..so i want to animate this so that the user's can see what is happening clearly ...so plzzzzzz..

Comment: Sorry, I can't help any further.

Comment: i guess i have received the needed information.thanks for the help.